# Can't bind to 'typeahead' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap

I'm using Angular 2.1.2 and I'm having trouble using ng2-bootstrap's typeahead feature, which I'm using version 1.1.16. I'm also using Webpack. I basically following the example on the website, but I adjusted it to use a service I have which will provide the search results for the typeahead field. Any idea why I'm getting this error? I'm also wondering why it says "elected" in the error message instead of "selected" like I have in the HTML below.

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'typeahead' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("elected | json}}</pre>
                    <input [(ngModel)]="selected"
                           [ERROR ->][typeahead]="chipFamilies"
                           (typeaheadOnSelect)="typeaheadOnSelect($event)""): AppComponent@76:27 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Template parse errors:(…) Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'typeahead' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("elected | json}}</pre>
                    <input [(ngModel)]="selected"
                           [ERROR ->][typeahead]="chipFamilies"
                           (typeaheadOnSelect)="typeaheadOnSelect($event)""): AppComponent@76:27
    at TemplateParser.parse (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:94:2), <anonymous>:7711:21)
    at RuntimeCompiler._compileTemplate (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:94:2), <anonymous>:17193:53)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:94:2), <anonymous>:17098:85)
    at Set.forEach (native)
    at compile (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/vendor.js:94:2), <anonymous>:17098:49)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.js:2294:2), <anonymous>:232:26)
    at Zone.run (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.js:2294:2), <anonymous>:114:43)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.js:2294:2), <anonymous>:502:57)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.js:2294:2), <anonymous>:265:35)
    at Zone.runTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.js:2294:2), <anonymous>:154:47)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.js:2294:2), <anonymous>:401:35)
```

HTML:

```
     <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
            <div class="form-group">
                <pre class="card card-block card-header">Model: {{selected | json}}</pre>
                <input [(ngModel)]="selected"
                       [typeahead]="chipFamilies"
                       (typeaheadOnSelect)="typeaheadOnSelect($event)"
                       class="form-control" style="width: 250px;" placeholder="Search Chip Families">

            </div>
        </form>
```

TypeScript:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import '../css/main.css';

import {ChipFamilyService} from './chip-family/chip-family.service';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

import { TypeaheadMatch } from '../../node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/components/typeahead/typeahead-match.class';

import { IChipFamily } from './chip-family/chip-family';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: require('./app.component.html'),
    providers: [ChipFamilyService]
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    public typeaheadLoading:boolean = false;
    public typeaheadNoResults:boolean = false;
    public dataSource:Observable<any>;
    public asyncSelected:string = '';
    public selected: string = '';
    chipFamilies: Array<IChipFamily>;
    errorMessage: string;

    public constructor(private _adminService: ChipFamilyService) {
        this.dataSource = Observable.create((observer:any) => {
            // Runs on every search
            observer.next(this.asyncSelected);
        }).mergeMap((token:string) => this.getChipFamiliesAsObservable(token));
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this._adminService.getChipFamilies().subscribe(
            chipFamilies => this.chipFamilies = chipFamilies,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
        );
        console.log('AppComponent initializing...');
    }

    public getChipFamiliesAsObservable(token:string):Observable<any> {
        let query = new RegExp(token, 'ig');

        return Observable.of(
            this.chipFamilies.filter((chipFamily:any) => {
                return query.test(chipFamily.name);
            })
        );
    }
    public changeTypeaheadLoading(e:boolean):void {
        this.typeaheadLoading = e;
    }

    public changeTypeaheadNoResults(e:boolean):void {
        this.typeaheadNoResults = e;
    }

    public typeaheadOnSelect(e:TypeaheadMatch):void {
        console.log('Selected value: ', e.value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should probably import the `TypeaheadModule` into your `NgModule` definition of your app:

```
import {TypeaheadModule} from 'ng2-bootstrap/components/typeahead';

@NgModule({
    imports : [
        //...
        TypeaheadModule
    ],
    //...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Yup, that was it and adding a `name` attribute to the search field.

Answer (score 3):

Import the TypeaheadModule from ngx-bootstap and make sure to install the module in npm using:

> npm i ngx-typeahead

```
 import { TypeaheadModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/typeahead';
// or
import { TypeaheadModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  imports: [TypeaheadModule.forRoot(),...]
})
export class AppModule(){}
```

Answer (score 0):

After applying the indicated recommendations, make sure that the component containing the input has been declared in the module